# How are these not equivalent ways of calculating a moving average

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to create a moving average on a column.  Here is the loop implemented two different ways:

Method 1

```py
for j in range (0,len(dataset_train)):
    dataset_train.loc[j+1,'TR'] = max(
        abs(dataset_train.loc[j+1,'High']-dataset_train.loc[j+1,'Low']),
        abs(dataset_train.loc[j,'Close']-dataset_train.loc[j+1,'Low']),
        abs(dataset_train.loc[j+1,'High']-dataset_train.loc[j,'Close']),
    )
    dataset_train.loc[j+13, 'ATR'] = dataset_train.loc[j:j+13,'TR'].sum()/14
```

Method 2

```py
for j in range (0,len(dataset_train)):
    dataset_train.loc[j+1,'TR'] = max(
        abs(dataset_train.loc[j+1,'High']-dataset_train.loc[j+1,'Low']),
        abs(dataset_train.loc[j,'Close']-dataset_train.loc[j+1,'Low']),
        abs(dataset_train.loc[j+1,'High']-dataset_train.loc[j,'Close']),
    )
    dataset_train.loc[j+13, 'ATR'] = dataset_train.loc[j:j+13,'TR'].mean()
```

Method 1 yields 0.0002142857142857224 and Method 2 yields 0.0030000000000001137.  However, when I look at the first 14 values of the dataset via `print(dataset_train.loc[0:13, 'TR'].sum()/14)` and `print(dataset_train.loc[0:13,'TR'].mean()` I get the same answer for both: 0.0022857142857143514.

Is there something inconsistent about how the three pieces of code are working?  It would appear that if the index is at 0, they should all yield the same answer.

Edit:

Here is the data I am using:

```
print(dataset_train.loc[0:13,'TR'+i])
0     0.000
1     0.003
2     0.002
3     0.002
4     0.004
5     0.002
6     0.002
7     0.002
8     0.003
9     0.002
10    0.002
11    0.003
12    0.002
13    0.003
```

Comment: Please, add the content of `dataset_train` to your question.

Comment: Where exactly did you see the mismatch? I assume the last result line?

Comment: The mismatch is the very beginning of the dataset.

Comment: A function to take the mean should never depend on values `13` or `14`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mismatch is the last result line:

`.mean()` actually counts how many elements are there in the slice.

`.sum()/14` does not. It will divide by 14 no matter how many elements are actually sliced by `[j:j+13,'TR']`

Look at this:

```py
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l1[0:3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l1[1:4]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> l1[2:5]
[3, 4]
>>> l1[3:6]
[4]
>>> l1[4:7]
[]
```

Comment: I'm seeing the above loops break down at the very beginning of my dataframe.  In my case, I am checking 0:13.  The first 14 elements of the column.  I think this prevents the issue of not having enough values to sum.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need only, to Modify `for j in range (0,len(dataset_train)):` to `for j in range (0,len(dataset_train-13)):` because the results differences between the two methods should be located at the end of your data, where the number of the rest points will become less than 14.